# Sending radio button data to next activity

Tags: android, button, android-activity, radio-button

I'm trying to allow the user to enter their Name, and click on one of three radio buttons, and click on a submit button. And on the next activity, it will display their name and the radio button they selected. I've managed to be able to send the name, but I'm not sure how to send the radio button selection. Can someone help?

This is what I have in the main activity layout .xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/operatorName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/operator_name" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioShifts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio2"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/radio3"
        android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked" />
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="@string/button1"
    android:onClick="onButton1" />
```

And I have this in the main_activity .java file:

```
    public final static String OP_NAME = "com.cyapps.downtimer.OPNAME";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
        // Is the button now checked?
        boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
        // Check which radio button was clicked
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.radioButton1:
                if (checked)
                    break;
            case R.id.radioButton2:
                if (checked)
                    break;
            case R.id.radioButton3:
                if (checked)
                    break;
        }
/*        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WinderDTActivity.class);
        EditText button = (EditText) findViewById(RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        String radioChosen = button.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(RADIO_CHOSEN, radioChosen);*/
    }

    public void onButton1(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, WinderDTActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.operatorName);
        String opName = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(OP_NAME, opName);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The code in /* */ is what I think I should do.. But I'm not sure. Someone help please? I'll really appreciate it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String str; // store the text corresponding to  the RadioButton which is clicked 

   switch(view.getId()) {
                case R.id.radioButton1:
                    if (checked)
                     str = "button1Text";
                        break;
                case R.id.radioButton2:
                    if (checked) str = "button2Text";
                        break;
                case R.id.radioButton3:
                    if (checked) str = "button3Text";
                        break;
         }

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, WinderDTActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("radioChosen", str); // pass "str" to the next Activity
```

**EDIT :**  To recieve the data in the next activity, use

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String message= extras.getString("radioChosen");

}
```

Comment: Okay, so I've done this after the switch: `     Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, WinderDTActivity.class);
     intent2.putExtra(RADIO_CHOSEN, str);
     startActivity(intent2);` but then on the next activity class, it says "Local variable str is not used.."

Comment: Okay, nevermind, I see what I had done wrong in the code above. but now I put this in my next activity, and it still comes up blank. :( `        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String opName = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.OP_NAME);
        String str = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.RADIO_CHOSEN);
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(30);
        textView.setText(opName);
        textView.setText(str);
        setContentView(textView);`

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have updated my code. It should work now.

Comment: It says string message is not used. And couldn't I have left intent.putExtra(RADIO_CHOSEN, str); the way it was?

Comment: Yeah you can let RADIO_CHOSEN be as it was. But just make sure that it is the same in both the activities.

Comment: And 'String message is not used` is a warning which is coming because you have declared the variable and you might not be using it else where in the code.

Comment: Yes, I see that, did you mean to put String str instead then? Because I just copied it from yours, and that's what it said. :(

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error ? in the first activity or in the second activity ?

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the error. But now, when I do this for the second activity.java: `        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null){
         TextView textView = new TextView(this);
         String opName = extras.getString(MainActivity.OP_NAME);
         String str = extras.getString(MainActivity.RADIO_CHOSEN);
         textView.setTextSize(30);
         textView.setText(opName);
         textView.setText(str);
         setContentView(textView);
        }` I only see the radio button string when I run it, I don't see the name AND the radio button string.

Comment: Try this : `String opName = extras.getString(MainActivity.OP_NAME); String str = extras.getString(MainActivity.RADIO_CHOSEN); String myString = opName + "/" + str; textView.setText(mySTring);`

Comment: Get both the strings and then just concatenate them into a single string and display it.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for not responding or anything, I had midterms this week, but thanks for everything. The last thing you mentioned worked! Well, I did it somewhat differently, but thank you so much for the ideas and helping me get started. I really appreciate it.

Comment: It's alright man! I am glad that you finally got it working. Good luck ahead! Happy coding. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

**-** Use `switch` to get the Radio button selected.

```
switch (types.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
      case R.id.sit_down:
        intent.putExtra(SIT_DOWN, "sitdown");
        break;
      case R.id.take_out:
        intent.putExtra(TAKE_OUT, "takeout");
        break;

      }
```

**-** Now just do the `startActivity(intent);`