# Android: pass the value using intent and match the previous selected radiobutton when clicked on previous button

Tags: android, json

Need Help with setting radio button on *click previous/next button*.
       I'm using JSON object to create an survey questions. For each question, I have created an new activity such as surveyquestion1.java,surveyquestion2.java,surveyquestion3.java,....,surveyquestion10.java.I am trying to pass question and radiobutton text value in an json object.

Some question have radio button consisting two radio buttons or more,others question have image or text.First question haves yes/no radiobuttons.Based clicking event of yes/no , it's jump to specific activity.

I want to **pass the value using intent and match the previous selected radiobutton when clicked on next/prev button**.Can any one give me an hint or example for it.

//Surveyquetion.java

```
public class Survey {
private static JSONObject survey_response = new JSONObject();
private static String TAG = "HS_" + Survey.class.getSimpleName();

public static void init_response_object(Context context) {
    try {
        if ((null == SaveSharedPreference.getUserResponse(context)) || (SaveSharedPreference.getUserResponse(context).length() == 0)) {
            JSONArray question_array = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject question = new JSONObject();

            question.put("qid", 1);
            question.put("type", "multiple_choice");
            question.put("value", "");
            question.put("textvalue", "");
            question_array.put(question);

            question = new JSONObject();
            question.put("qid", 2);
            question.put("type", "image");
            question.put("value", "");
            question.put("textvalue", "");
            question_array.put(question);

            question = new JSONObject();
            question.put("qid", 3);
            question.put("type", "multiple_choice");
            question.put("value", "");
            question.put("textvalue", "");
            question_array.put(question);

            question = new JSONObject();
            question.put("qid", 4);
            question.put("type", "multiple_choice");
            question.put("value", "");
            question.put("textvalue", "");
            question_array.put(question);

            question = new JSONObject();
            question.put("qid", 5);
            question.put("type", "multiple_choice");
            question.put("value", "");
            question.put("textvalue", "");
            question_array.put(question);

            question = new JSONObject();
            question.put("qid", 6);
            question.put("type", "multiple_choice");
            question.put("value", "");
            question.put("textvalue", "");
            question_array.put(question);

            question = new JSONObject();
            question.put("qid", 7);
            question.put("type", "image");
            question.put("value", "");
            question.put("textvalue", "");
            question_array.put(question);

            question = new JSONObject();
            question.put("qid", 8);
            question.put("type", "text");
            question.put("value", "");
            question.put("textvalue", "");
            question_array.put(question);

            question = new JSONObject();
            question.put("qid", 9);
            question.put("type", "multiple_choice");
            question.put("value", "");
            question.put("textvalue", "");
            question_array.put(question);

            question = new JSONObject();
            question.put("qid", 10);
            question.put("type", "multiple_choice");
            question.put("value", "");
            question.put("textvalue", "");
            question_array.put(question);

            survey_response.put("urn", "nill");
            survey_response.put("data", question_array);

            SaveSharedPreference.setUserResponse(context, survey_response.toString());
            Log.d(TAG + "_SR", survey_response.toString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void manageAnswers(int qid, String value, Context context) {
    try {
        JSONObject userResponse = SaveSharedPreference.getUserResponse(context);
        JSONArray questions = userResponse.getJSONArray("data");

        if (1 == qid) {
            JSONObject question1 = questions.getJSONObject(0);
            if (qid == question1.getInt("qid")) {
                if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {

                    JSONObject question2 = questions.getJSONObject(1);
                    question2.put("value", "");
                    question2.put("textvalue", "");
                    questions.put(1, question2);

                    JSONObject question3 = questions.getJSONObject(2);
                    question3.put("value", "");
                    question3.put("textvalue", "");
                    questions.put(2, question3);

                    JSONObject question4 = questions.getJSONObject(3);
                    question4.put("value", "");
                    question4.put("textvalue", "");
                    questions.put(3, question4);

                    Log.d(TAG, "Q1 Ans is NO, hence resetting other questions - " + questions.toString());
                    userResponse.put("data", questions);
                    SaveSharedPreference.setUserResponse(context, userResponse.toString());
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ans : yes");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "ERROR, MISMATCH IN qid / index");
            }
        } else if (3 == qid) {
            JSONObject question3 = questions.getJSONObject(2);
            if (qid == question3.getInt("qid")) {
                if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {

                    JSONObject question4 = questions.getJSONObject(3);
                    question4.put("value", "");
                    question4.put("textvalue", "");
                    questions.put(3, question4);

                    JSONObject question5 = questions.getJSONObject(4);
                    question5.put("value", "");
                    question5.put("textvalue", "");
                    questions.put(4, question5);

                    Log.d(TAG, "Q3 Ans is YES, hence resetting other questions - " + questions.toString());
                    userResponse.put("data", questions);
                    SaveSharedPreference.setUserResponse(context, userResponse.toString());
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ans : no");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "ERROR, MISMATCH IN qid / index");
            }
        } else if (6 == qid) {
            JSONObject question6 = questions.getJSONObject(5);
            if (qid == question6.getInt("qid")) {
                if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("no")) {

                    JSONObject question7 = questions.getJSONObject(6);
                    question7.put("value", "");
                    question7.put("textvalue", "");
                    questions.put(6, question7);

                    Log.d(TAG, "Q6 Ans is NO, hence resetting other questions - " + questions.toString());
                    userResponse.put("data", questions);
                    SaveSharedPreference.setUserResponse(context, userResponse.toString());
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ans : yes");
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "ERROR, MISMATCH IN qid / index");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//using this as uservalue to set the radiobutton
public static String userValue(int prevQuestion,Context context) {
    String textValue = null;
    try {
        JSONObject userVal = SaveSharedPreference.getUserResponse(context);
        Log.d(TAG, "userVal:" + userVal.toString());

        JSONArray userTextVal = userVal.getJSONArray("data");
        Log.d(TAG, "userTextValue" + userTextVal.toString());

        for (int i = 0; i < userTextVal.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject us = userTextVal.getJSONObject(i);
            int quet = us.getInt("qid");
            if (quet == prevQuestion) {
                Log.d(TAG, "qId :" + quet);
                Log.d(TAG, "textvalue :" + us.getString("textvalue"));
                textValue = us.getString("textvalue");
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return textValue;
}

public static int prev(int qid, Context context) {
    int returnValue = -1;
    int count;
    try {
        JSONArray userPos = SaveSharedPreference.getUserResponsePosition(context);
        /*ArrayList<String> pos = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < userPos.length(); i++) {
            pos.add(userPos.getString(i).trim());
        }*/
        // count = pos.size();
        count = userPos.length();
        Log.d(TAG, "userPos : " + userPos.toString());
    Log.d(TAG, "count : " + count);
        if (count > 0) {
            // returnValue = Integer.parseInt((pos.get(count - 1)));
            returnValue = (int) userPos.get(count - 1);
            Log.d(TAG, "position : " + returnValue);

    //resetting the position
            userPos.remove(count - 1);
            SaveSharedPreference.setUserResponsePosition(context, userPos.toString());
        } else {
            returnValue = -1;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnValue;
}

public static String next(int qid, String value, Context context) {

    // RESET UNWANTED ANSWERS
    Survey.manageAnswers(qid, value, context);

    String returnValue = "";
    JSONArray positionArray = SaveSharedPreference.getUserResponsePosition(context);
    if (null == positionArray || positionArray.length() > 8) {
        positionArray = new JSONArray();
    }
    positionArray.put(qid);
    SaveSharedPreference.setUserResponsePosition(context, positionArray.toString());

    try {
        JSONObject submitData = SaveSharedPreference.getUserResponse(context);
        submitData.put("urn", SaveSharedPreference.getCurrentURN(context));
        JSONArray dataArray = submitData.getJSONArray("data");

        if (1 == qid) {

            JSONObject question = dataArray.getJSONObject(0);
            question.put("qid", qid);
            question.put("type", "multiple_choice");

            if (value.toLowerCase().equals("yes")) {
                question.put("value", 1);
                returnValue = "2";
            } else if (value.toLowerCase().equals("no")) {
                question.put("value", 2);
                returnValue = "5";
            }
            dataArray.put(0, question);
            question.put("textvalue", value);
        } else if (2 == qid) {

            JSONObject question = dataArray.getJSONObject(1);
            question.put("qid", qid);
            question.put("type", "image");
            question.put("value", value);
            returnValue = "3";
            dataArray.put(1, question);
            question.put("textvalue", value);
        } else if (3 == qid) {

            JSONObject question = dataArray.getJSONObject(2);
            question.put("qid", qid);
            question.put("type", "multiple_choice");

            if (value.toLowerCase().equals("yes")) {
                question.put("value", 3);
                returnValue = "6";
            } else if (value.toLowerCase().equals("no")) {
                question.put("value", 4);
                returnValue = "4";
            }
            dataArray.put(2, question);
            question.put("textvalue", value);
        } 
    .
    .   
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .   

        } else if (10 == qid) {

            JSONObject question = dataArray.getJSONObject(9);
            question.put("qid", qid);
            question.put("type", "multiple_choice");

            if (value.toLowerCase().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("something")) {
                question.put("value", 19);
            } else if (value.toLowerCase().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("something")) {
                question.put("value", 20);
            } else if (value.toLowerCase().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("something")) {
                question.put("value", 21);
            } else if (value.toLowerCase().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("something")) {
                question.put("value", 22);
            } else if (value.toLowerCase().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("something")) {
                question.put("value", 23);
            }

            returnValue = "";
            dataArray.put(9, question);
            question.put("textvalue", value);
        }

        submitData.put("data", dataArray);
        SaveSharedPreference.setUserResponse(context, submitData.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnValue;
}
}
```

//Surveyquestion2.java

```
      prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int prevQuestion = (Survey.prev(1, context));
            String val=Survey.userValue(prevQuestion,context);
            Log.d(TAG,"prevQusetionValue :" +val);
            Log.d(TAG, "prevQuestion : " + String.valueOf(prevQuestion));
            if (9 == prevQuestion) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SurveryQuestion1.this, SurveryQuestion9.class);
                intent.putExtra("value",val);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });

      next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            if (-1 == selectedId) {
                Toast.makeText(SurveryQuestion1.this, "Please answer to proceed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                String answer = radioButton.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                Log.d(TAG, "Answer : " + answer);
                if ((null != answer) && (answer.length() > 0)) {
                    String nextQuestion = Survey.next(1, answer, context);
                    if (2 == Integer.valueOf(nextQuestion)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SurveryQuestion1.this, SurveryQuestion2.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else if (5 == Integer.valueOf(nextQuestion)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SurveryQuestion1.this, SurveryQuestion5.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

//SavedPreferences.java

```
    public static void setUserResponse(Context ctx, String userResponse) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(ctx).edit();
    editor.putString(PREF_USER_RESPONSE, userResponse);
    editor.commit();
}

public static JSONObject getUserResponse(Context ctx) {
    String response = getSharedPreferences(ctx).getString(PREF_USER_RESPONSE, "").toString();
    JSONObject userResponse = null;
    try {
        if (null != response && response.length() > 0) {
            userResponse = new JSONObject(response);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        userResponse = null;
    }
    return userResponse;
}
```

Note:1.using Json Object .2 not using Fragmentactivity

I tried to set the  value of radiobutton using this method in onCreate() in an new activity before the click events.Give me error:- Null Pointer Execption for radioButton1.getText()

SurveyQuestion1.java

```
    radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb_yes);
        String check= (String) radioButton1.getText().toString();//Null Pointer Exception
        Log.d(TAG,"check"+check);*/
        radioButton2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rb_no);
        if (check.equalsIgnoreCase(prevValue)) {
            radioButton1.setChecked(true);
        }
        else {
            radioButton2.setChecked(true);
        }
prev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SurveryQuestion9.this, SurveryMgmt.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // CREATE A DUMMY JSON
                Survey.init_response_object(context);

                // INIT USER POSITION
                SaveSharedPreference.setUserResponsePosition(context, new JSONArray().toString());

                int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                if (-1 == selectedId) {
                    Toast.makeText(SurveryQuestion9.this, "Please answer to proceed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
                    String answer = radioButton.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();
                    String nextQuestion = Survey.next(9, answer, context);
                    if (1 == Integer.valueOf(nextQuestion)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SurveryQuestion9.this, SurveryQuestion1.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    } else if (10 == Integer.valueOf(nextQuestion)) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SurveryQuestion9.this, SurveryQuestion10.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks in advance

Comment: please reformat your question, you did not indent it correctly

Comment: Can briefly tell me what problem with intent..how to resolve that issue.. please give me some hints...@GrayCygnus

Comment: see that "}' hanging out?... you should indent (4 spaces per level) correctly your code, I see you missed 4 spaces on each line so it is at the same level

Comment: i have reformatted questions..can u guys help me..@GrayCygnus

Comment: You have created new activity per question? Or there is 1 activity in which question changes?

Comment: i have created new activity per question. @Payal

Answer (score 0):

Create a single activity and add view per question. Have a global counter and next() and previous() method. Load your view with counter==0 for 1st question and save the response in model. When you press next button call next() and increment counter adding view with next question. If you go previous, fetch saved data from model and update your radio button with that value. 
This would be make your code manageable and can be extended later on without any extra effort.

```
Class Xyz extends Activity
{
  int counter=0; 
  onCreate()
  {
    loadView(0);
  }

  loadView(int index)
  {
   //if value is already saved then rtetrieve from model or load with default value
  }
   // called on next button click
  next()
  {
   index++;
   loadView(index);
  }
  // called on previous button click
  previous()
  {
   index--;
   loadView(index);
  }

  save() 
  {//save in model }



}
```

Comment: yes that's true..i would like to create the code like that.. for now can give me hint for setting value of radiobuttons in the new activity..

Comment: please check my question i have added an null pointer exception part @Payal

Comment: Well, for that refer to this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12862987/sending-radio-button-data-to-next-activity-in-android

Comment: ya,that's one way of passing radio button.What if i want to pass the radio button to previous activity.consider surveyquestion1 as first activity then surveyquestion2.java as second.

Comment: ya,that's one way of passing radio button to next activity.What if i want to pass the radio button to previous activity.consider surveyquestion1 as first activity then surveyquestion2.java as second activity. From surveyquestion2, i want it to pass to the surveyquestion1 selected value...   @Payal

Comment: same way..you are calling activity1 from activity2. in activity one's oncreate check if intent.getExtras !=null then update your answer with the value of intent